# ADAL native application token expires after 12 hours

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, adal, autorest

I've created the .net console application which is the client of my web api. Both apps are registered in azure. I want my console app to run without user interaction. Console app checks the message queue and if the message arrives, it does some calculation and sends back the data to my web api. I use adal to authenticate my connection. I authenticate by secret key. Since my client uses generated code by AutoRest I added DelegatingHandler to catch every request and add the authorization header before i send it:

```
public class ClientHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        AuthenticationContext authContext = Constants.authContext;
        ClientCredential clientCredential = Constants.clientCredential;
        string apiId = Constants.apiId;
        string tokenType = Constants.tokenType;

        // ADAL includes token in memory cache, so this call will only send a message to the server if the cached token is expired.
        var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(apiId, clientCredential);
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(tokenType, result.AccessToken);

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

As you can see I am using already defined authorization context. Thanks to code above I can get the token without user interaction. And this work just fine! **However** after **12 hours** the application starts returning `Unauthorized` error. The question is how do I prevent it? I thought that `AcquireToken` method takes care of the token expiration. Am I missing something?

**EDIT:**
Constant class:

```
public static class Constants
{
    public static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["aadInstance"];
    public static string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["aadTenantName"];
    // this application id
    public static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientApi:ClientId"];
    // the key which it can be authenticated
    public static string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientApi:AppKey"];
    // the id of the api
    public static string apiId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiId"];
    public static string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);
    public static string tokenType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TokenType"];
    public static AuthenticationContext authContext = null;
    public static ClientCredential clientCredential = null;

    public static async Task<TokenCredentials> Authenticate()
    {
        authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
        var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(apiId, clientCredential);
        return new TokenCredentials(result.AccessToken, tokenType);
    }
}
```

Comment: How you define AuthenticationContext in Constants?

Comment: @CuongLe Included Constants class.

Comment: create `AuthenticationContext` everytime, you don't need to keep it as static on `Constant`

Comment: @CuongLe Are you sure this will help? (You know I will be sure if it works after another 12 hours, or maybe there is a way to test it faster?) What about server calls? If i create the `AuthorizationContext` every time doesn't it mean that the cache is recreated and will call the azure server with every request?

Comment: @CuongLe Creating  `AuthenticationContext` everytime I send the request, helped (the application is now running 30 hours without an error) I also checked what requests are being send, and it seems once the application is authenticated it doesn't send the request to the azure server - which is good. You can create a new answer if you want so I can mark it as solved. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the code to create `AuthenticationContext` everytime and noneed to keep it as `static` on `Constants` class

Answer (score 0):

> The question is how do I prevent it?

According to official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes), Access Token Lifetime is between 10 minutes to 1 day. So we can extend the Access token lifetime up to 1 days, but we can't prevent it expiration. We also can get the way how to Configurable Token Lifetimes in Azure Active Directory from the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes).

> A malicious actor that has obtained an access token can use it for extent of its lifetime. Adjusting access token lifetime is a trade-off between improving system performance and increasing the amount of time that the client retains access after the user’s account is disabled.

We can use refresh token to otain new access/fresh token when the current access token expires. And the refresh token default expiration 14 days. So we no need to call all the azure server with every request. We also can get according ExpiresOn when we get the access token. If the access token is not expired then we no need to get the access token.

`var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(apiId, clientCredential)`;

[image]